Running commands before saving sessions with persistence.nvim?
https://github.com/folke/persistence.nvim
The readme just lists events to be called without further explanation. PersistenceSavePre would be the one before saving a session. I looked at this issue showing this snippet, which the user reports doesn't work.
        vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("PersistenceSavePre", {
            desc = "Fix neo-tree before saving",
            -- group = "persistence",
            callback = function()
                print("savePre")
            end,
        })

Folke replied with :h 'User' (the single quotes did confuse me a bit), this is what :h User (capital U) outputs but I tried and don't know how to put so and so together. OP didn't respond with a solution either and closed it.
User                Not executed automatically.  Use |:doautocmd|
                to trigger this, typically for "custom events"
                in a plugin.  Example: >
                    :autocmd User MyPlugin echom 'got MyPlugin event'
                    :doautocmd User MyPlugin



All events in Vim are predefined. The complete list is given at :h autocmd.txt There's simply no way for any user code/plugin to create a new one.
And so when plugin's docs mention some unknown "event XXX" it actually means "event User with pattern XXX". That's also what listed at :h User.
Also note that event's pattern is actually "an argument" that is passed from event's creator to autocmd code. For the most of predefined events it's a buffer name. But not for all by any means. In particular, for the "User" event it's some sort of signature meaningful only for the user code that fires the event.

I got answers in a few places including here, and got it working now
        vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("User", {
          pattern = "PersistenceSavePre",
          callback = function()
            vim.cmd(":Neotree close")
          end,
        })

